# Dependency in xml file

Tags: magento-1.9, xml

I want dependency in etc/modules/xml file

How to use dependency in xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <SM_Example>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </SM_Example>
    </modules>
</config>
```

This module is depend on SM_Rate i mean i m using foreign key of this module table SM_Rate in this SM_Example so when i install this two module than some time it give error SM_Rate this module is not exist bcz of  this module  SM_Example is install first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your declaration xml file look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <SM_Example>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <SM_Rate>
            </depends>
        </SM_Example>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you don't know how to do smth, look how magento do that. For example:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Captcha>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>core</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Customer />
                <Mage_Adminhtml />
            </depends>
        </Mage_Captcha>
    </modules>
</config>
```